# Certificate invalid?

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, ssl

I'm not sure what caused this, but my Chrome detected the certificate from ***.stackexchange.com** invalid for **discuss.area51.stackexchange.com**

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I've done:

1. Open [this user's chat profile page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/174169/henry-wh-hack-v2-1) from the IPS chatroom Awkward Silence.
2. Open the [parent user link](https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/157965/henry-wh-hack-v2-1) from that profile page.

---

Tried to open the parent user link from Microsoft Edge and it also return error.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: For me as well.

Comment: Wrong URL. Use correct URL and you'll be fine.

Comment: So basically just remove the *s* from the https eh? Thanks!